# How to customize Sliding tab viewpager in android

Tags: android, android-tabs

I am developing an android application which uses sliding Viewpager of Tabs.(i.e).Sliding Tabs.
I have used the code from https://github.com/vgrec/SlidingMenuWithViewpager.
It works well.
and now I want to customize tabs underline/tabs background color.
 My Screenshot is shown below.
[image]
How could I do this?Thanks.

Comment: Use custom xml file for each tab, inflate this xml file and set in tab indicator i.e setIndicator(your xml file view)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Replace the content of your left_menu.xml file with this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/left_menu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#CCC"
    android:orientation="vertical" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/org.grec">

    <com.astuetz.viewpager.extensions.PagerSlidingTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        app:shouldExpand="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_height="48dip"
        android:background="#00FF00"
app:indicatorColor="#FF0000"
app:underlineColor="#F6CECE" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/tabs" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have tested it see the snapshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add these fileds in xml file left_menu.xml. To change colors add your own color codes.

```
<com.astuetz.viewpager.extensions.PagerSlidingTabStrip
android:background="#fff"
app:indicatorColor="#BDBDBD"
app:underlineColor="#F6CECE" .../>
```